# Best way to rotate weekly message?

Tags: php

I am trying to build a form that will rotate a message on a weekly basis, and if no new message exists, return to the first message in the table and cycle back through. I have included a rough edit of what I have already tried and it works to an extent. The issue with the current code is that it doesn't work properly for the first week or after cycling through once. Pretty new to this so hopefully someone can help me figure out a better way to to do this.

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "pass";
$db = "forms";

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)or die("Cannot connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db)or die("Cannot select DB." . mysql_error());

function datediff($interval, $datefrom, $dateto, $using_timestamps = false) {
    /*
    $interval can be:
    yyyy - Number of full years
    q - Number of full quarters
    m - Number of full months
    y - Difference between day numbers
        (eg 1st Jan 2004 is "1", the first day. 2nd Feb 2003 is "33". The datediff is "-32".)
    d - Number of full days
    w - Number of full weekdays
    ww - Number of full weeks
    h - Number of full hours
    n - Number of full minutes
    s - Number of full seconds (default)
    */

    if (!$using_timestamps) {
        $datefrom = strtotime($datefrom, 0);
        $dateto = strtotime($dateto, 0);
    }
    $difference = $dateto - $datefrom; // Difference in seconds

    switch($interval) {

    case 'yyyy': // Number of full years
        $years_difference = floor($difference / 31536000);
        if (mktime(date("H", $datefrom), date("i", $datefrom), date("s", $datefrom), date("n", $datefrom), date("j", $datefrom), date("Y", $datefrom)+$years_difference) > $dateto) {
            $years_difference--;
        }
        if (mktime(date("H", $dateto), date("i", $dateto), date("s", $dateto), date("n", $dateto), date("j", $dateto), date("Y", $dateto)-($years_difference+1)) > $datefrom) {
            $years_difference++;
        }
        $datediff = $years_difference;
        break;
    case "q": // Number of full quarters
        $quarters_difference = floor($difference / 8035200);
        while (mktime(date("H", $datefrom), date("i", $datefrom), date("s", $datefrom), date("n", $datefrom)+($quarters_difference*3), date("j", $dateto), date("Y", $datefrom)) < $dateto) {
            $months_difference++;
        }
        $quarters_difference--;
        $datediff = $quarters_difference;
        break;
    case "m": // Number of full months
        $months_difference = floor($difference / 2678400);
        while (mktime(date("H", $datefrom), date("i", $datefrom), date("s", $datefrom), date("n", $datefrom)+($months_difference), date("j", $dateto), date("Y", $datefrom)) < $dateto) {
            $months_difference++;
        }
        $months_difference--;
        $datediff = $months_difference;
        break;
    case 'y': // Difference between day numbers
        $datediff = date("z", $dateto) - date("z", $datefrom);
        break;
    case "d": // Number of full days
        $datediff = floor($difference / 86400);
        break;
    case "w": // Number of full weekdays
        $days_difference = floor($difference / 86400);
        $weeks_difference = floor($days_difference / 7); // Complete weeks
        $first_day = date("w", $datefrom);
        $days_remainder = floor($days_difference % 7);
        $odd_days = $first_day + $days_remainder; // Do we have a Saturday or Sunday in the remainder?
        if ($odd_days > 7) { // Sunday
            $days_remainder--;
        }
        if ($odd_days > 6) { // Saturday
            $days_remainder--;
        }
        $datediff = ($weeks_difference * 5) + $days_remainder;
        break;
    case "ww": // Number of full weeks
        $datediff = floor($difference / 604800);
        break;
    case "h": // Number of full hours
        $datediff = floor($difference / 3600);
        break;
    case "n": // Number of full minutes
        $datediff = floor($difference / 60);
        break;
    default: // Number of full seconds (default)
        $datediff = $difference;
        break;
    }    
    return $datediff;
}


$current_date = date("d F Y");
$date_difference = datediff('ww', '1 December 2015', $current_date, false);
    $sql_count = "SELECT * FROM forms.quotes";
    $query_count = mysql_query($sql_count);

$row_count = mysql_num_rows($query_count);
$key = true;

while($key)
{
    if($row_count < $date_difference)
    {
        $date_difference = $date_difference - $row_count;
        $key = true;
    } else {
        $key = false;
    }
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM forms.quotes WHERE id = '$date_difference'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

            echo "<body bgcolor='#4E2F91'><font color='#dfcd6b'><i>";
            echo $row['message'];
            echo "</i></font></body>";
    }
echo mysql_error();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: please do not use `mysql_*` functions. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` (in examples) instead.

**First** of all you have to select appropriate quote for current week. You can do so storing shown date in database:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM forms.quotes WHERE WEEK(date_shown)=:week_number AND YEAR(date_shown)=:year LIMIT 1');
$sth->bindParam(':week_number', date('W'));
$sth->bindParam(':year', date('Y'));
```

**Next** you have to update oldest shown quote with current date if nothing was found in first select statement:

```
UPDATE forms.quotes SET shown.date = NOW() ORDER BY shown_date ASC LIMIT 1;
```

And repeat step #1 - now you should have a result.

If you want to manipulate results in select statements (add a new quote for curtain week and be sure it will show up), you can add `ORDER BY created_at DESC` statement or similar in select clause.